# LIVEVALIDATION plugin JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, dom, responsetext, livevalidation

good afternoon ,

I hope you are well

I have the following problem :

Use the add LiveValidation ( http://livevalidation.com/examples )

to validate form fields .

the form is loaded in the master page so dynamic HTML with AJAX

to do this , validations with LiveValidation not work but

when the form is loaded with AJAX but embeds the code of the form

in the HTML page it works.

I searched online and apparently is because calling the form with AJAX

IDs Form INPUT fields are loaded in the DOM of the HTML page

for this reason it should make the call validations after the sentencing

ResponseText , I've done it this way and it has worked when I put

the validation of the first field , but not when I put the validation

of all fields.

CURRENT CODE ----- ------

TEACHER PAGE :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script src="LIVEVALIDATION.js" language="JavaScript"> < / script>
<SCRIPT>

AJAX CODE TO LOAD THE FORM

< / SCRIPT >
< / HEAD >
<BODY>

<DIV id="container">

here the form is loaded

< / DIV >

< / BODY>
< / HTML >
```

FORM :

```
<FORM>

<INPUT TYPE="text"  ID="F1">

<SCRIPT>
var f1 = new LiveValidation ( ' f1 ');
f1.add ( Validate.Presence ) ;
< / SCRIPT >

< / FORM>
```

----- SUGGESTED CODE ( BUT DOES NOT FULLY ) ------

TEACHER PAGE :

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script src="LIVEVALIDATION.js"  language="JavaScript"> < / script>

<SCRIPT>

CARGAFORMULARIO function ()
{
.
.
.
  if ( conexion1.readyState == 4 )
  {
    responseText ...... ;


    var f1 = new LiveValidation ( ' f1 ');
    f1.add ( Validate.Presence ) ;



  }
  else
    if ( conexion1.readyState == 1 | | conexion1.readyState == 2 | |         conexion1.readyState   == 3 )
        {
      ...
       }
    }



    < / SCRIPT >

    <BODY>

    <DIV id="container">

    here the form is loaded

    < / DIV >

    < / BODY>
    < / HTML >
```

----- ------ CODE THAT JOB

MASTER PAGE :

```
    <HTML>
    <HEAD>
    <script src="LIVEVALIDATION.js" language="JavaScript"> < / script>
    < / HEAD >
    <BODY>

    <DIV id="container">

     <FORM>

    <INPUT TYPE="text" ID="F1">

    <SCRIPT>
    var f1 = new LiveValidation ( ' f1 ');
    f1.add ( Validate.Presence ) ;
    < / SCRIPT >

    < / FORM>

    < / DIV >

    < / BODY>
 < / HTML >
```

MATTER : javascript function that loads the form is called via a link that sends data
containing form fields for the user to change and save the changes .

thank you very much

Comment: Make sure you're [closing your HTML tags properly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Introduction#Tags) "Closing tags are the same as the start tag but also contain a forward slash immediately after the leading less-than sign". Also, from the same MDN page: "Tag names may be written in either upper or lower case. However, the W3C (the global consortium that maintains the HTML standard) recommends using lower case (and XHTML requires lower case)."

Comment: thanks for your answer, I require that the validation work with LiveValidation loading the form with ajax.